# Remove leading zeros from a column in a text file in Python and then merging the similar rows with same strings of two text files into one

Tags: python, csv, merge

Suppose I have 2 files-

```
File 1:

00023 apple
00632 banana
00020 cat
00290 dog
00004 egg
00089 hen
00310 ink
```

```
File 2:

45 fan
23 jar
339 goat
4 kite
310 land
```

So first in File 1, I need to trim the leading zeroes from column 1. We will get something like this:

```
23 apple
632 banana
20 cat
290 dog
4 egg
89 hen
310 ink
```

After this, I want to compare the File 1 and File 2 for the common numbers (in this case 23, 4, 310) and then merge the common columns into a new file and produce a output similar to this-

```
23 apple jar
4 egg kite
310 ink land
```

I have gone through some answers here but could not really comprehend as I am still new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module from the standard library.

First, read each file into a dictionary, using a dictionary comprehension (the [str.lstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) method can be used to remove the leading zeros.

Next find the common keys by taking advantage of the fact that dictionary key views support set operations like [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection).

Finally, write the common keys and associated values to a new csv file.

```py
import csv 


with open('csv1.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data1 = {col1.lstrip('0'): col2 for col1, col2 in reader}


with open('csv2.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data2 = {col1: col2 for col1, col2 in reader}


common_keys = data1.keys() & data2.keys()


with open('merge.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for key in common_keys:
        writer.writerow([key, data1[key], data2[key]])
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can easily check your values. I have tried it with following source Code.
I first created two dataframes (you already have) with a list with values from 0 to 399:

```
    import pandas
    df1 = pandas.DataFrame({"col1": list(range(400))})
    df2 = df1
```

Then you initialize a list with your searching Indexes and iterate threw this list.

```
  search_idx = [23, 4, 310]
```

Your dataframe objects has columns. Each column has a name. In my example: I only have one column and the column has the name "col1". The column name is a field of your dataframe object so you can access it with the dot-operation.

```
   #Open the file
   with open('merge.txt', 'a') as file:
        
       #Iterate over all indexes       
       for idx in search_idx:

           #Write Values to list
           values = [idx, df1.col1[idx], df2.col1[idx]]
          
           #convert to string
           values = map(str, values)

           #Concatenate to one string and write to file
           text = " ".join(values)
           file.write(text + '\n')
```

This creates a file merge.txt with following data:

```
    23 23 23
    4 4 4
    310 310 310
```

if you want a "," between the data change the "join" line in the iteration

Best regards

Comment: I guess this is not the output I wanted that I described in the question above, can you give another look at my question? @SirBaum

Comment: this is just because I initialized this dataframe with numbers. Try it with your own dataframe